# Find the work done in pumping all the water out of the tank through a spout 6 feet above the top of the tank.

Tags: calculus

A conical tank, full of water, has a radius of 10 feet at the top and an altitude of 8 feet. Find the work done in pumping all the water out of the tank through a spout 6 feet above the top of the tank.

$$62.5\pi \int_0^8 (10-\frac54y)^2 (y+6) \,dy= (400000\pi)/3$$

This is how I set up the integral and then my answer, I think its wrong but I am unsure of how to properly set up this problem.

Please help me, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why and how you came to this integral?

Comment: I used the formula W = F * D           I used this formula because we are suppose to figure out the parts for each and then use the integral to find the work done

Comment: Why do you integrate from $0$ to $2$?

Comment: Oh, my bad that is suppose to be 0 to 8

Comment: And the radius of the cone at the altitude $-8$ feet should be equal to zero. It is not so in your proposal. And what is the $62.5$ coefficient?

Comment: The 62.5 is weight density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tank is an upside down cone. Let's choose $y=0$ to be at the vertex. At $y=8$ the radius of the horizontal cross section is $10$, so at any intermediate $y$ the radius is $$r=y\frac{10}8$$
The volume of a disk full of water at height $y$ and thickness $dy$ is then $$dV=\pi r^2(y) dy=\pi\frac {25}{16}y^2dy$$
The work done to move this water is $$dW=\rho g dV\cdot(6+(8-y))$$
Here $\rho g$ is the weight density. You need to move the water to the top of the tank $(8-y)$ feet, then extra $6$ feet to the spout. So $$W=\int_0^8dW=62.5\pi\frac{25}{16}\int_0^8y^2(14-y)dy$$

**Note:** I think yours is similar, except that you chose $y=0$ at the top of the tank, and $y$ increasing towards the bottom.

Comment: Note that I've had a small mistake, where I've put 10 instead of 8. The numberical answer is same as yours